# How Can I Reboot Elastic Beanstalk Instances in an ebextensions script?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to run an rpm command, then yum update, then reboot the instance for changes to take affect.

My ebextensions script works if I remove the **03reboot** command. When I add it in, it fails and I get the event errors:

```
Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001]
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) '<id>'. Aborting the operation.

commands:
    03reboot:
        command: shutdown -r now
```

Is there a preferred way to issue a reboot in the ebextensions config?

Comment: I wonder if it is a permissions issue. Have you tried `shutdown` with `sudo`?

Comment: The commands are already running as root so sudo isn't necessary. Valid point though. I'm beginning to think that it simply isn't possible to configure EBS to reboot during instance deployment. I've even tried sneaking the script into an undocumented post-deployment directory as pointed out here: http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/ and it still fails.

Comment: Okay, your guess might be right. Is there any information in the logs about the failure to `shutdown -r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you don't. The recommendation from AWS support is to use a custom AMI that you pre-configure and use for instance replacement going forward.